# How to include Retina images in Timber?

Tags: timber

I'd really like to improve my website (built with Timber) for Retina displays and browsed through past issues on GitHub as well as the Docs. So I added a srcset and used the retina filter (which is deprecated?) and that retina resizing works quite well, but not really in conjunction with the standard resize filter. Also, I saw that there's an ImageHelper class which provides a `retina_resize` function/filter(?), but I'm not quite sure how to use it.

This is my code right now:

`<img srcset="{{ TimberImage(image).src | resize(208) | retina(1) }} 1x, {{ TimberImage(image).src | retina(2) | resize(416) | retina(2) }}  2x">`

Any tips about the best practices for Retina-ready images in Timber are greatly appreciated :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best approach is to create a Macro that will generate the HTML markup for you. I use a Macro that takes an image ID and will check the media width and output the appropriate HTML for retina images.

You can view the Macro that I created [here](https://github.com/Objectivco/objectiv-starter-theme/blob/master/views/_macros/_img.twig).

You would then use the Macro like this to generate the appropriate HTML

```
{% import '_macros/_img.twig' as m_img %}
{{m_img.fixed(imageId, 50, {alt: 'post thumbnail', class: 'fixed'})}}
```

Comment: Thanks man, your solution is pretty neat and worked perfectly! :)

Comment: Thanks @Artifex404! I didn't know that existed. Looks great!